# Steroids with Parse back-end retrieve nested object

Tags: object, parse-platform, nested, steroids

I am developing an app with Supersonic and Parse as back-end. I have two classes with one to one relationship (imagine something like "course" and "teacher", with each course held by one teacher). 
I am using the function of the supersonic.model find() to retrieve one course that include an attribute "teacher" which is the pointer to related record in the teacher class. How can I configure Parse in order to get all the information of the nested object (teacher in that case) directly when I call the find() function?
So instead of having

```
{ "course": {
   "name" = "Math",
   "school" = 'London Business School",
   "teacher" = '3edrr3rf'
}
```

having:

```
{ "course": {
   "name" = "Math"
   "school" = 'London Business School"
   "teacher": {
        "firstname" = "Sandra",
        "lastname" = "Jackson",
        "age" = "45"
   }
}
```

Thanks,
Damiano